# Strange Form problem: cffile not working

Tags: forms, coldfusion, upload, cffile

Hmmm...strange problems...

I'm making a form to upload syllabi. Basically, someone go search for a course and select the button next to the course that says "Upload Syllabi." Next, a window will popup prompting them for the file. I pass this page info to insert the URL into the database etc.

```
<input name="upload" type="button" value = "Upload Syllabi" id = "uploads" onclick = "window.open('upload_syllabi.cfm?course=#course#&semest=#semester#&ref=#refnum#','popup','width=350,height=170,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0')"/>
```

It is passed to this page:

```
<cfset session.semester = #url.semest#>
<cfset session.course = #url.course#>
<cfset session.ref = #url.ref#>



    <form name = "uploadForm" enctype = "multipart/form-data" action = "upload_action.cfm">
    <table align="center" class = "contenttable">
      <tr>
        <td><h3>Upload Syllabi for <cfoutput><b>#session.semester# #session.course# #session.ref#</b></cfoutput></h3> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
    <input name="syllabiUpload" id = "uploader" type="file" />

    </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="submit" name="uploaded" id="uploaded" value="Upload" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><a href="javascript:window.close();">[close]</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

I had originally had no session variables...but I was having some problems with url.semest...and I had just ended up leaving them there.

Anyway...when the form is submitted it should go to this page:
upload_action.cfm

```
<cffile action="upload" filefield="syllabiUpload" destination="#SyllabiLoc#" nameconflict="makeunique">
<cfset SyllabiURL = "#SyllabiPath##cffile.serverfile#">

<cfquery name="checkSyllabi" datasource="#sacsds#" username="#sacsuser#" password="#sacsuser#">
SELECT  *
FROM    faculty.dbo.Syllabi
WHERE   faculty.dbo.syllabi.Semester = '#session.semester#' 
AND     faculty.dbo.syllabi.Refnum = '#session.ref#'
</cfquery>

    <cfif getSyllabi.recordCount is 0>
    <cfelse>
    <cffile action="delete" file = "#checkSyllabi.url#">   
    </cfif>

    <cfquery name="updateSyllabi" datasource="#sacsds#" username="#sacsuser#" password="#sacsuser#">
    UPDATE faculty.dbo.Syllabi
    SET url = '#SyllabiURL#'
    WHERE Semester = '#session.semester#' 
    AND  Refnum = '#session.ref#'
    </cfquery>
 <table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Uploaded</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

I get this error when I click the submit button:

**Invalid content type: ''.
The cffile action="upload" requires forms to use enctype="multipart/form-data".**

Kind of weird...cause I definitely  have that line of code in my form...

hm....

EDIT: Continue Problem # 2.

Getting this error:

File D:\ColdFusion8\runtime\servers\coldfusion\SERVER-INF\temp\wwwroot-tmp\http://uwf.edu/acad/Syllabi/Introduction to Maritime Studies Syllabus2.rtf specified in action delete does not exist.

Did i do the cffile delete wrong?
:\ Not sure..

Comment: Figured out why I am getting the errorr. Thanks.

Comment: Solution to problem 2: 

<cffile action="delete" file = "#SyllabiLoc##Right(checkSyllabi.url, len(checkSyllabi.url)-27)#">

Comment: @Bri - Before you resort to string functions, why is the value incorrect in the first place. In particular, why is there a reference to the temp directory D:\ColdFusion8\runtime\servers\coldfusion\SERVER-INF\temp\wwwroot-tmp... ?

Comment: honestly, the person who originally made this system did so in a strange way because of the way our servers are setup. My department doesn't control our server. :( ...because I'm just a student...and kind of not so good at the application part of coldfusion...I built off of what was already created ...somewhat. It is an old system I am trying to revise. I honestly have no idea what that reference means... ; ; The fact that ... most of the useful tags don't work... also plays a part... I can thank my IT department... sigh.

Comment: Well, obviously I do not know the values of your variables or site structure. But usually there are cleaner ways of constructing file paths than with string functions. What are the values of #SyllabiLoc# and #checkSyllabi.url#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could be a browser issue or you have some kind of anti-virus, proxy or firewall messing with the upload. As you say, you are telling the browser to use the right encoding so presumably that is getting lost in translation somewhere.

Option 2 is you are seeing cached pages and not the version with the correct form. Try clearing out your browser cache.

EDIT: Actually the problem is simple. You haven't told it to use method="POST" on the form.

Comment: one more question pertaining to this... 

editing it in the question above